# Как редактировать виджет от другого сайта если он завернут в ifFrame

Tags: javascript, html

такой вопрос есть онлайн чат Re:plain я хочу отключить рекламу для него так как у меня есть платная подписка, как видно на скриншоте где я выделил там реклама есть но этот чат находится в блоке ifFrame как мне сделать так что бы этот текст пропал? + Мне нужно картинку на верху "Re:" поменять на свою, как это сделать? "Если можно я новичок по простому"

[image: Вот скриншот]

Comment: Управлять данными в iframe не получится, если только сам сайт не предоставляет таких возможностей

Comment: Понял спасибо за ответ.